# What period is P99 or P95 calculated over?

Tags: latency

When committing to/setting SLAs for a service, what time period should the SLA be calculated over?

For example, if I wanted all the services in my organization to commit to P95 latency, and one of the services commits to 500ms, what is the time window - because the P95 will be different based on the time window we look at.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on in what cycles your latency fluctuates.

No daily / hourly peaks? A couple thousand samples do just fine.

Daily fluctuations (e.g. peak usage, concurrent backups etc.)? Then you will need to measure at least a whole day.

Weekly fluctuations (e.g. tied to work hours or evening activities etc.)? Then you will need to sample over a full week.

There is no strict requirement to sample *everything* over the chosen time window, but your time window better be representative or you may be held liable. Also make sure to be fair when you under-sample.

If you want to be on the safe side, take the worst-case-scenario in your load cycle, and within that scenario take a full minute worth of samples. That gives you a good estimate what will be held *against you*.